# What does a fourth physical dimension look like?

Tags: internal-consistency, spacetime-dimensions

I'm not sure how this isn't a question yet, it might be irrational or impossible to answer, but...

What would a fourth physical dimension look like, if one existed? As opposed to 3D, what about 4D?

Comment: Time is the fourth dimension.

Comment: It would look exactly like three dimensions to us, since that's all we can see.  Otherwise, look at http://miegakure.com/

Comment: A fourth physical dimesion, I mean

Comment: Why does no-one understand that we cannot understand any dimensions beyond our own?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon that's because we *can* understand dimensions beyond our own. Advanced mathematics does it *all* the time.

Comment: It is actually rather good question, even if somewhat poorly worded. Since the Huygens principle does not work in spaces with even dimensions, light impulses would not just pass by the observer - there would be a lingering, diminishing "afterglow". This affects also reflected light, so the vision would be quite different. How different and what would the world look like is difficult to guess.

Comment: If you are talking about a 4th spatial dimension, it would look like something that is likely indescribable. If not, the 4th dimension is typically time, and there are a number of theories that propose more dimensions (at least up to eleven with some string theories IIRC). Either way, I doubt most people can wrap their brain around that.

Comment: Is this not a physics question?

Comment: Youtube has some fun videos by educational Sources that can explore some possibilities, but i don't have time now to go find specific ones now. None the less if you can find some of them, they can be quite informative

Comment: @Bellerephon No, this is about the subjective reality of the observer. It's closer to physiology or the psychology of vision. Physics.SE deals with objective reality. "What would the laws of physics be like with a 4th physical dimension?" might be a physics question.

Comment: As already mentioned by Ryan, there are a lot of resources online dealing with the 4th dimension, and its representation/look, they go from material for kids that are simplified and rather amusing to the long boring material. A bit of googling will tell you all you need and more

Comment: look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_382806&feature=iv&src_vid=fXNiv_PGYJs&v=lLg3oLbwRsQ) it unfolds the fourth dimension in the 3ed. looks like 3 dimensions but by running around you find out that something is odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asking what the 4th dimension looks like is like trying to explain "blue" to a blind man.

Our perception of reality is inside our heads. Using the example of color, "blue" is our perception of light with a wavelength between around 450 and 495 nm. This absolute, technical description of the color blue does nothing to describe how we humans perceive "blue".

Trying to imagine the 4th dimension is the same way. Our brains evolved with 3 physical dimensions, so that's what they can perceive. We cannot accurately imagine what a 4th dimension would look like anymore than a blind man can imagine "blue". Color is an illusion (there's a great [Vsauce video about that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evQsOFQju08)), and so is our perception of the 3rd dimension. These things subjective experiences which are only in your own head are known as [qualia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia) and cannot be experienced by anyone else.

All our senses are illusions. The answer to "what does the fourth dimension look like" is "whatever our brain evolves to make it look like". Whatever perception of the 4th dimension is evolutionary advantageous, that's what it will look like. I know, not very satisfying.

---

What we can do is use analogy to understand why we cannot understand. We can conceive of a being which can only see in 2 dimensions, and our struggles to explain a 3rd to them. What is "up"? What is "down"? How can two people occupy the same space at the same time, just one is "above" the other? These can be understood intellectually, but not viscerally.

This is the subject of the famous book [Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland) wherein A Square, a 2 dimensional being, recounts his encounters with A Sphere, a 3 dimensional one. It's a beautiful analogy of the difficulties involved in understanding higher dimensions, as well as commentary on Victorian social hierarchy. You can read the whole thing online; it's from 1884 and in the public domain. Plenty of links to online editions at the bottom of its Wikipedia page. I highly recommend it.

---

Going back to the color analogy, the 4th dimension is *even harder to imagine* because no human has ever perceived it. A better analogy than trying to describe "blue" to a blind man is trying to describe ["infrared"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared) to anyone. No human has ever directly perceived "infrared". No human can describe how we would perceive it. Every time you're shown "infrared" it's a [false color projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color) to give you an idea what it would be like to see infrared, but it requires hijacking some other color.

Similarly we can, to a certain extent, perceive the 4th dimension through projections. We're familiar with projecting 3 dimensional objects onto 2 dimensions, like a TV screen or this drawing of a cube.

[image: A cube]

Foreshortening and shading tricks our brain into perceiving 3 dimensions when there are only 2. We can do it for the 4th dimension... sort of.

[image: By Vitaly Ostrosablin - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31380489]

[*By Vitaly Ostrosablin CC BY-SA 3.0*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31380489)

What that animation is attempting to illustrate is how to make a [tesseract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract), a 4D cube.

- 0 dimensions: A point.
- 1 dimension: A line, drawn between 2 points.
- 2 dimensions: A square, drawn with 4 lines.
- 3 dimensions: A cube, drawn with 6 squares.
- 4 dimensions: A tesseract, drawn with 8 cubes.

Even with this 2D projection, it's still hard to hold in your head what an object whose faces are cubes looks like and how you would interact with it.

Comment: *"Color is an illusion ... and so is our perception of the 3rd dimension."* Third dimension? Really?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, 3D is real but our *perception* of 3D, what it "looks like", is in our heads. Like color, which is our perception of wavelengths of light, what our brain actually receives is electrical impulses from patterns of nerves firing in response to receiving photons of various wavelengths and at various rates, one from each eyeball. It has to translate that into images, not always accurately. This is 2D information. We don't directly perceive 3D. We stitch that together from the slight differences between what is received by our two eyeballs due to their parallax.

Comment: Nice answer, but one thing I'd add is that just as you can project the "shadow" of a wireframe 3D cube onto a 2D plane, as shown in [this illustration](https://www.learner.org/courses/mathilluminated/images/units/5/1958.png) from [this site](https://www.learner.org/courses/mathilluminated/units/5/textbook/04.php) (which has a lot of other helpful illustrations on ways of representing higher-dimensional shapes in lower-dimensional spaces), so you can use a computer to calculate the shadow of 4D hypercube on 3D space while the cube is rotating,

Comment: (continued) giving animations like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-WyreE9ZkI) and [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtSNStVW81M). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rG6aIVGquOg) also has a hypercube animation starting at 9:16, along with some other nice animations illustrating things like the cross-sections of 4D figures with our 3D "plane".

Comment: Love your reference to The Wise Man's Fear (about the color blue).

Answer (score 2):

A lot of how a four-dimensional world behaves is going to depend on how the physical laws change with the addition of another dimension. For example, gravity needs to work differently, otherwise [there would be no stable orbits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/50142/gravity-in-other-dimensions-than-3-and-stable-orbits/50147#50147).

If you're trying to picture what a four-dimensional world would look like once these issues have been dealt with (or handwaved away), then the simplest way to explain it is that it would be the same as ours, but with more space. For example, a planet would be a hypersphere, so the amount of surface it has is proportional to the cube of its radius (in 3D it's proportional to the square of its radius).

One way to get a mental image of a 4D setting is to put the fourth dimension on the time axis. For example [here's an MRI, a 3D scan of someone's head, put into a 2D gif](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/NPH_MRI_274.gif). In that gif, height, a spatial dimension, is mapped onto the time axis. Now take a gif of something 3D ([like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Glacier_Valley_formation-_Formaci%C3%B3n_Valle_glaciar.gif)) and apply the same idea to it - try to picture it not as something changing over time, but changing as you move along the fourth dimension.

Also, it's going to take some time to really wrap your head around this idea. You're not used to thinking in 4D, so expect it to take some time before you get a more intuitive understanding of what it looks like. The good news is that it can be done - I don't have a link handy but I've read a paper that demonstrated that people are able to gain an intuitive understanding of 4D space after playing with a 4D computer program for a while.

Answer (score 1):

This has no singular answer.  We live in 3 dimensions.  Thus, when we talk about "3d" we have source material to use: the world around us.  When we talk about how to handle the 4th dimension, its really up to the world builder to decide how it behaves.

The most scientifically plausible answer to "what does a 4th dimension look like" is to consider what a 3rd dimension "looks like."  After all, if you think about it, the world "looks" like whatever photons get painted onto our retinas as we go about our business.  There's a natural reduction of dimensionality from 3d to 2d that occurs in our eyeballs.  That reduction is what causes effects like vanishing points, and explains why something that's closer can cover up something that's further away.

Mathematicians have captured this concept with something called "perspective rendering."  It's what we use when we create realistic drawings.  This concept can be extended to 4 dimensions, permitting us to reduce a 4d shape into a 2d shape.

Of course, its not always easy to see.  Consider this cube:
[image: Necker Cube]

This is the Necker Cube, which is intentionally shapes to give no depth cues.  It's not immediately obvious which side is facing towards us.  In fact, if you know what you're doing, you can make the cube alternate which direction it's facing, just by convincing yourself which side is closer to you.  In fact, its so easy to do this, that with a few subtle depth hints, we can convince you that you're looking at an object that is, in fact, impossible to construct:
[image]

This problem is typically solved by adding some rotation to the mix.  If we rotate the cube, we can quickly see which side is which.  Stack Exchange wont let me use animated gifs here, but this [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syl5Yk25E-g) shows a rotating cube which has a quite obvious front and back because of its movement.

We can apply this in 4 dimensions, using the same mathematical principles as the 3d case.  The object [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5Qh2XpoCsY) is a hypercube, rotating just like the cube above. What looks like a deformation is actually just the effect of perspective as the object rotates.  It's no more strange than the fact that a sheet of paper looks like a line when you rotate it to look at it on edge.  The only difference is that you spent years learning that that piece of paper is behaving "normally."  In fact, you can be surprised when objects are not normal, such as in the [Ames room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCV2Ba5wrcs):
[image: Ames room]

There is, in fact, no practical limit to this process, so we can [explore many different hypercubes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-x4P65EKjt0), including those in 5 and 6 spatial dimensions